# Magento 1.9: Clear Magento Order Model

Tags: magento-1.9, model

I'm trying to loop through a lot of order ids and fetching the order data but performing a `clearInstance()` on an order model variable doesn't seem to clear the data and I keep getting the same data. Has anyone else experienced this? For now I'm having to just use this which uses up way too much memory.

```
Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order['order_id'])
```

Comment: Can you please add the code you have tried before?

Answer (score 0):

You need to unset variable in which you are storing the data of order.

Also you need to check you are passing correct value in  `$order['order_id']`

Reference :http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php

Comment: -> clearInstance() should do that. See the explanation here. http://dusanlukic.com/clearing-magento-model-instance

Comment: @David , can you write your full code in question. so i can help you in it.